# Fokker-Planck: Uncertainty Propagation

Tags: probability, error-analysis, stochastic-processes

I am interested in propagating the probability density function along the sampled trajectories having parametric uncertainty $a$. However I discovered that the fokker-planck equation for that system indicates that probability density function stays constant through time. Consider a very basic dynamical system:

$\dot{x} = a$

$\dot{a} = 0$

where a is constant in time and considered as parametric uncertainty in the system.

Applying method of characteristics gives the following ODE for propagating the density along the sampled trajectory:

$\frac{dp}{dt} = - (\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{2}})p$

Which is zero for the problem at hand. Isn't it contradictory since under parametric uncertainty (or initial state uncertainty) the domain of x spreads and therefore the probability of the sampled trajectory should give 0? However since each trajectory is a deterministic function of the uncertain initial conditions of the parameter $a$, I understand that the probability of the trajectories shouldn't change. However by definition of the PDF, the integral of the PDF should give 1 which is not possible if the probability doesn't change with expanding support domain.

Sorry for any misunderstandings, I am quite new to this topic and after facing this paradox, I want to know where I am thinking wrong.